How to programmatically click play button in YouTube via puppeteer?
I am trying to play a video via YouTube using puppeteer using C#
Here's my code so far:
If you can provide me with or guide me correct way appreciate it a lot:
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using PuppeteerSharp;

namespace SOYoutube
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Define the URL of the question
            string questionUrl = "www.youtube.com";

            // Download the Chromium revision if not already done
            var browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher();
            await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync();

            // Launch a new browser instance
            await using var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
            {
                Headless = false // Set to true if you want to run in headless mode
            });

            // Open a new page
            await using var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();

            // Navigate to the question page
            await page.GoToAsync(questionUrl);

            // Wait for the upvote button to be present in the DOM
            await page.WaitForSelectorAsync("");

            // Click the upvote button
            await page.ClickAsync("");

        

            // Keep the browser open for a while to observe the action
            await Task.Delay(5000);

            // Close the browser
            await browser.CloseAsync();
        }
    }
}

Page only open only not playing any video

So you have a WaitForSelectorAsync call with a comment "Wait for the upvote button to be present in the DOM". Have you tried making a selector for the Play button? In case it helps, in firefox that button is rendered as <button class="ytp-play-button ytp-button" aria-keyshortcuts="k" data-title-no-tooltip="Play" aria-label="Play keyboard shortcut k" title="Play (k)">

Before you play the video you need to wait until the network is idle and DOM content is loaded to the page. Then you can click on play. Refer to the code for more reference:
using PuppeteerSharp;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await PlayYouTubeVideo();
    }

    static async Task PlayYouTubeVideo()
    {
        var launchOptions = new LaunchOptions
        {
            Headless = false
        };

        using (var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(launchOptions))
        using (var page = await browser.NewPageAsync())
        {
            try
            {
                await page.GoToAsync("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYYdmLkRKRQ", waitUntil: new[] { WaitUntilNavigation.Networkidle2 }); // Give your URL here
                await page.WaitForSelectorAsync(".html5-video-container", new WaitForSelectorOptions { Timeout = 5000 });
                var playButton = await page.QuerySelectorAsync(".ytp-play-button");
                await playButton.ClickAsync();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}

